# Do <script> elements work inside an SVG file, inside an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg

I would like to create an SVG file that, on it's own, has a little animation, controlled by Javascript. Let's assume that I must use Javascript, not [the fancy-pants SVG animation tools](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html). That works just fine; a black circle moves around the top left corner of my window:

```xml
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="400px" height="400px"
    >
  <circle id="c" cx="50px" cy="50px" r="20px" />
  <script>
    var c = document.getElementById('c');
    function f() {
      c.setAttribute('cx', 50 + 30 * Math.random());
      c.setAttribute('cy', 50 + 30 * Math.random());
    }
    setInterval(f, 1000);
  </script>
</svg>
```

Now, I would like add that SVG to a few web pages. Let's try:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test a scripted SVG in an &lt;img&gt; tag
  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="test.svg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The result is a black circle that does not move around.

**What am I doing wrong?** or **Where does it say that I cannot do this?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<script>` elements do work in SVG files but not when the SVG file is displayed as an image whether that is via the `<img>` element or as a CSS background-image. If you want scripts to work then replace the `<img>` with an `<iframe>` or `<object>` element.

Basically, SVG when used in an image context emulates raster images. Raster images aren't scriptable so neither is SVG when it is used in that way.

Comment: "SVG when used in an image context emulates raster images" ← So there is no security vulnerability when using `<img src="evil.svg">`? Even though a `<script>` tag would be inside the SVG?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this and it worked for me.

But I think there should be the mysterious [`//<!\[CDATA\[`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784200/607407) stuff:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC
  "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
  <svg width="200"
       height="200"
       zoomAndPan="disable"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       xml:space="preserve">
    <!-- Script linked from the outside-->
    <script xlink:href="linked_script.js" />
    <script>
      //<![CDATA[
        alert("ble");
      ]]>
    </script>
  </svg>
```

This is the file I [embed](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SVG_in_HTML) it in (and it `alert`s as expected):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title>Svg embeding test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <embed src="test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" /> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: SVG is considered XML. HTML is a little more lenient, so the `CDATA` isn't required. However, in SVG, `CDATA` *is always* required.

Comment: Yes, was just confirming your suspicion.

Comment: Oh - I'm not used to positive comments :D

Comment: `CDATA` isn't required in <script> inside svg, but is nice because then you don't have to escape all `<` characters one-by-one. If you don't use that character it'll work just fine without `CDATA`.

Comment: @ErikDahlström: It's not so simple, other characters are also affected: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2784183/309483

Comment: @JanusTroelsen you're absolutely right, though my point still stands - the svg spec doesn't require the use of explicit CDATA sections in script elements.

Comment: But this does not work with the `<img />` tag, wright?

Answer (score 0):

Following Robert Longson answer: 
In my case I had to `<embed>` the .svg because my CMS (joomla) didn't allow me to put a src attribute into the object tag and also worked.

Also you have to be sure that MIME type image/svg+xml is allowed on your server.

Comment: object tags don't have a src attribute, they do have a **data** attribute so if joomla stopped you using src it was right to do so.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your clarification !